# How to know that which extension is calling which one in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

First thing is that I am new at Asterisk, and I want to know about calling. I am making Java-Asterisk application. So, I just need direction that how will I be able to know that which caller is calling which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asterisk AMI event interface and parse event. That is hard way

Simple way - orginize dialplan so it inform you when someone call someone(by put record in db or any other method).

Comment: Thanks man. You gave me right direction. I am going to do this hard way :) because at some point we will have to use external database.

Comment: External database can be used via func_odbc using dialplan.